# Data Driven Unit test on ClassInitialize

Tags: c#, testing, mstest

I am trying to run some test with different values each time. For example: I have 3 methods: `methodA`, `methodB`, and `methodC`. I want to run each method twice with a different Index location. I have `TestInitialize` and `ClassInitialize` methods.

1. I tried using `ClassInitialize` but I wasn't successful; I am getting compile time error because my test context is not static.

   ```
   public TestContext TestContext
   {
      get { return testContextInstance; }
      set { testContextInstance = value; }
   }

   [DeploymentItem("UI.Framework.IntegrationTests\\ExpectedValues.xml")]
   [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|DataDirectory|\\ExpectedValues.xml", "searchTerm2", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
   [ClassInitialize()]
   publicstaticvoid ClassInitialize(TestContext context)
   {        
      string indexPath = TestContext.DataRow[0].ToString();
      bool isSuccess1 = SearchApiTestsHelper.InitializeSearchEngine(indexPath, null);
      Assert.IsTrue(isSuccess1);
   }
   ```

   I couldn't do this.
2. I tried using `TestInitialize` but the data row was not being loaded, it was `null`.

   ```
   [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML",
               "|DataDirectory|\\ExpectedValues.xml", 
               "indices", 
               DataAccessMethod.Sequential),
   TestInitialize()]
   public void MyTestInitialize()
   {
       string indexPath = TestContext.DataRow[0].ToString();
       bool isSuccess1 = SearchApiTestsHelper.InitializeSearchEngine(indexPath, null);
       Assert.IsTrue(isSuccess1);
   }
   ```
3. I know I can set each method to run twice however, some methods require different data for validation. e.g `method2` still needs to run twice for each index location and for each run assert a set of expected values from the data source.

   ```
   [DeploymentItem("UI.Framework.IntegrationTests\\ExpectedValues.xml")]
   [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML",
               "|DataDirectory|\\ExpectedValues.xml", 
               "pb1", DataAccessMethod.Sequential),
    TestCategory("Integration")]
   [TestMethod]
   public void PhraseBoosting()
   {
       expectedVal = TestContext.DataRow[0].ToString();
   }
   ```

   How can this be archived?

Comment: what does your ExpectedValues.xml look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming an XML file like this:

```
<Values>
  <searchTerm2>this is search term 2</searchTerm2>
  <indices>these are the indices</indices>
  <pb1>personal best?</pb1>
</Values>
```

You can access the values like so:

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        //[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|DataDirectory|\\ExpectedValues.xml", "Values", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
        //[ClassInitialize]
        //public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
        //{
        //    string indexPath = testContext.DataRow["searchTerm2"].ToString();
        //    Console.WriteLine(indexPath);
        //}

        [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|DataDirectory|\\ExpectedValues.xml", "Values", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
        [TestInitialize]
        public void TestInitialize()
        {
            string indexPath = TestContext.DataRow["indices"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(indexPath);
        }

        [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|DataDirectory|\\ExpectedValues.xml", "Values", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]        
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            string indexPath = TestContext.DataRow["pb1"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(indexPath);
        }
    }
```

The class initialize method doesn't seem to work. I am not sure if this is by design.

Comment: Yes, it is by design. `ClassInitialize` runs only once for the whole  test run, and the DataSource has not initialized yet.

Comment: This solution does NOT work if you try to run another test method. TestInitialize grabs the values from the current running test. So if the running test does not have the values from the xml, it wont work. Try adding another method TestMethod2 which has a different Table and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Data Driven test at class initialize level is not supported in VS Unit Test Framework. the only option is to use it at TestMethod level. I hope they add this to next version.